# Understanding the fast sweeping algorithm for Eikonal equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

[image]

[image]

My question comes from the paper "*A Fast Sweeping Method For Eikonal Equations*" by HongKai Zhao. Specifically, I have no clue why the first inequality stated after the statement of **Theorem 3.6.** holds. It seems that the algorithm (2.2) implies that the "$\geq 0$" should be "$=0$". Thank you for your help!